# Flash .Net tie-in

Tags: .net, flash, membership

I'd like to have placeholders in an .swf file that I can populate with information from .Net Membership information.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using fsCommand() in your action script to pass XML back and forth between Flash and .NET.

Answer (score 1):

by .Net membership, are you refering to MS .NET? If so, 2 suggestions 1) use Silverlight 2) if you can't use silverlight, serialize the .NET info to XML then read the XML from flash to populate the SWF.